# Error reassigning a value to an object property

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I can get the value, but not reassign another one; why?

```
export default class RemCpPluginHandler<
    SourceType extends StdMap<string | number>
> extends StdFileBasedPluginHandler<StdMap<string | number>> {
    constructor(configuration: CollectorConfiguration) {
        super(configuration);

        this.dataProcessor.recordPreProcessor.preprocessRecord = (
            record: SourceType
        ) => {
            const newCountry = record.COUNTRY.toString().replace(
                /[0-9]*\. /gi,
                ""
            );
            record.COUNTRY = newCountry;
            return record;
        };
    }
}
```

In record.COUNTRY = newCountry; I have the error:
**Property 'COUNTRY' does not exist on type 'SourceType'<b**r>
SourceType extend the interface StdMap<T = string> {[key: string]: T;}

Comment: Assuming that `interface StdMap<T = string> {[key: string]: T;}` and `interface SourceType extends StdMap{}` there is no way, that `... = record.COUNTRY.toString()...` (why using toString anyway?) throws no error, but `record.COUNTRY = ..` does. If `SourceType` is defined differently, show the definition.

Comment: toString() because without it the compiler throws an error; SourceType is not defined differently.

Comment: That does not make any sense. There is something wrong in some other parts of the code. With only the parts shown, a recent version of typescript does not throw any compilation errors

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code; note that if I remove SourceType and declare record as StdMap<string | number>, no compilation errors are thrown; but SourceType extends StdMap<string | number>, so why errors?

Comment: Ok. At least now we know, why you need the `toString()` in the assignment, because `COUNTRY`  may be a `number` or a `string` and you can't call `replace` on a `number`. The other issue I can't explain, but as this is a quite complex situation with generics and type extension, there may be an issue with type inference.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing the type of the input parameter: from

```
record: SourceType
```

to

```
record: {COUNTRY: string}
```

It is still unclear why the compiler throws the value assignment error.